# iPhone mini device not dismissed view controller properly

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios15

I am trying to presenting `BViewController` (subclass of `UIViewController`) from `AViewController` (sub class of `UIView` controller). Its presenting view without issues but after dismissing view controller from `BViewController` to `AViewController` its not dismissing properly.

[image]
[image]

[image]

This issue occurs only in iPhone 13 mini and iPhone 12 mini (simulators). Remaining devices it is working fine.

Presenting view controller code

```
func pushToNextVC()
{
    let vc = getStoryBoard()?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextVC") as! NextVC
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Dimiss view controller code

```
@IBAction func backTOVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: The information is not sufficient, unfortunately. Could you provide some essential code snippets showing how exactly you present and dismiss these view controllers?

Comment: @lazarevzubov Thanks for your reply.
please check the updated Question with code block.

Comment: Thanks! It's not entirely clear, the code looks OK (in general), so maybe the problem is somewhere else. Does any of your view controllers have transparent background? It might cause problems in some circumstances. Also, have you tried using `.fullScreen` as the `modalPresentationStyle`?